# Change folder name in server

Tags: 301-redirect

If I change a folder name in server ant thus the URL will be changed, could I perform 301 redirection or this is only for the case that the web page has been transferred to another folder?

Answer (score 1):

Entire folders can be redirected, just like files can.  You can add a line like this to `.htaccess`:

```
Redirect permanent /OLD http://example.com/NEW
```

Which will cause every file in the directory to be 301 redirected:

- `http://example.com/OLD/page_one.html` -> `http://example.com/NEW/page_one.html`
- `http://example.com/OLD/page_two.html` -> `http://example.com/NEW/page_two.html`
- `http://example.com/OLD/an_image.png` -> `http://example.com/NEW/an_image.png`

This is documented in [Apache's mod_alias redirect documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

Comment: So even in the case that it is for dynamic web pages (phpbb forum), according to you a single code line in the .htaccess folder is enough for such a redirection?

Comment: Yes, redirects are very simple to implement.

Comment: Please note that I have seen here: http://www.htaccessredirect.net/index.php and the code that arises for such a case is:                                   //301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 http://example.com/OLD/(.*)       http://example.com/NEW//$1                                             So it is not exactly as specified by you

Comment: `RedirectMatch` works as well, but it is not needed.  `RedirectMatch` directives take more processing since they rely on regular expressions.  Plain `Redirect` directives should be preferred when they work.  The redirect documentation that I linked shows a very similar example with a folder redirected to a different subdomain and `foo.txt` being redirected inside it.

Comment: I have seen in the server that the .htaccess exists in www as well as in public_html... would it be the same either the one or the other to be changed? Moreover, could you please let me know where this code shall be added or it is not necessary to be added in specific place

Comment: The specific folder structure can vary.  Your web host's set up is not like mine at all.  You may have to experiment to find the correct file.  Redirect rules can generally be added anywhere in the .htaccess file, as long as they are on their own line.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL has changed, you'll need a redirect. If a certain page was in site.com/folder1 before and is now in site.com.folder2, you'll need to redirect it. A 301 redirect is for the case that a page has been transferred to another folder, but for all practical purposes, changing the folders name is the same as putting the files in a different folder.